# Best way to add Custom LoginModule to my web application

Tags: security, authentication, jboss, authorization

I need to implement User lockout in my web application which uses `DatabaseServerLoginModule` and `JBoss5`. I am planning to write a custom login module class to achieve this. My next question is: where should I put my custom login module class? After some research I found couple of solutions:

1. Deploy the login module class in a JAR as a standalone module, independent of the webapp
2. Deploy the login module class as a part of the webapp in a JAR inside `WEB-INF/lib/`

My web application will be packaged and shipped to the customer and customers install this package and JBoss separately on a Server. My question is: Where should I put my custom login module class?
Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I were the data center, I would expect *two* packages:

- One containing the login module
- and another one for the real application

Reasons

- The data center might have special responsibilities regarding sensitive user data, authentication etc. So in case of a login module, they might even have a special internal review process (this is normally not applied on an ordinary application). In order to avoid this review with each application update, a separate package is preferred. In order to have a quick review, a small package is better.
- There might be other applications which use the same login module
- A data center must be paranoid: An application which ships with it's own authentication could be abused to install a back door. Again internal or legal requirements may not even allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please provide more details as I new to web application security

Comment: @JavaDeveloper1 Your question is related to login module packaging. Which reason should I explain further?